# How to read csv. files with vectors in data.table package?

Tags: r, data.table

I created a tibble (named df) with a number and a vector inside:

```
library(tsibble)
library(data.table)

df <- tibble(var1 = 5, var2 = list(c(1,2,3)))

var1   var2
 5   c(1,2,3)
```

Then I saved this tibble as a csv. file like so:

```
data.table::fwrite(df, file = "C/MyFolder/file.csv")
```

Now I want to read this file:

```
df <- data.table::fread(file = "C/MyFolder/file.csv")
```

And I get new tibble with number and text inside a cell:

```
 var1   var2
   5    1|2|3
```

How to correctly read a csv. file in order to get again a tibble with a vector inside a cell?

Comment: The short answer is, you can't: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1162

Comment: @MichaelChirico You are wrong, I adapted the received answer and it works well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might not be able to do it in one fell swoop, but here's a custom function that will solve your problem.

## Custom Function

The function `str_as_vct()` is defined as follows:

```
str_as_vct <- function(x, sep = "|", transform = as.numeric, ...) {
  sapply(
    X = base::strsplit(
      x = x,
      split = sep,
      fixed = TRUE
    ),
    FUN = transform,
    ... = ...,
    simplify = FALSE,
    USE.NAMES = FALSE
  )
}
```

### Description

Take a vector of `character` strings, each with values separated by a delimiter, and split each string into a vector of its values.

### Usage

**`x`**: A vector of `character` strings, which represent vectors as delimited values.

**`sep`**: A `character` string. The delimiter used by the strings in `x`.

**`transform`**: A function to transform `character` vectors into vectors of the desired datatype.

**`...`**: Further arguments to the `transform` function.

## Solution

Armed with `str_as_vct()`, your problem can be solved in a single assignment:

```
df <- data.table::fread(file = "C/MyFolder/file.csv")[
  # Select all rows.
  ,
  
  # Select and transform columns.
  .(var1, var2 = str_as_vct(var2))
]
```

## Result

Given an initial `df` like this

```
df <- tibble(
  var1 = 1:3,
  var2 = list(
    c(1, 2, 3),
    c(4, 5, 6),
    c(7, 8, 9)
  )
)
```

the solution should yield a `data.table` with the following `str()`

```
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ var1: int  1 2 3
 $ var2:List of 3
  ..$ : num  1 2 3
  ..$ : num  4 5 6
  ..$ : num  7 8 9
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

where each element of `var2` is a `numeric` vector.

Conversion to a `tibble` via `as_tibble(df)` will yield:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
   var1 var2     
  <int> <list>   
1     1 <dbl [3]>
2     2 <dbl [3]>
3     3 <dbl [3]>
```

Comment: Thanks, works, marked as correct. Question: what if there are many columns and where the vectors are, I don't know in advance.

Comment: @JackPo Could you clarify?  It sounds like you're asking two things: **(1)** what to do if `var2` contains an unknown distribution of some strings like `"1|2|3"` (which represent vectors) and other strings like `"stuff"`; and **(2)** what to do if there are many columns like `var2`.

Comment: I simplified the question and you gave the correct answer. In reality, I have a tibble with many columns and some of them may contain a vector

Comment: @JackPo Hmmm...that's a bit more complicated.  You might have a hard time distinguishing between **(1)** cells containing numeric vectors like `c(1,2,3)` that were *transformed* into strings like `"1|2|3"`; and **(2)** cells that contained strings like `"1|2|3"` *to begin with*. You might use `df %>% across(everything(), str_as_vct)` with the **`dplyr`** package, but you might have to build in checks to prevent ineligible columns from being transformed into `NA`s.

Comment: @JackPo Also, thank you for marking my answer as accepted! Would you kindly upvote as well?

Comment: @Grec I got the idea, thanks

Comment: Correction: You might use `df %>%` **`mutate(`** `across(everything(), str_as_vct)` **`)`** with the **`dplyr`** package.  I left out **`mutate()`** in my previous comments.

Comment: @Grec Thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `csv` file is seperated by `|` so you need in `fread` the seperator argument like:

```
fread(file = "file.csv", sep="|")
```

Greetings

Comment: Your solution works if there is one cell in the table, but if there are several of them, then the result is strange (the cells are merged and another cell is added). I would like to find a universal solution.